# Effect of adding Ethernet 10/100 printers to a gigabit network

Tags: ethernet, gigabit-ethernet

Everything here is gigabit (NICs, router and switch) except for two ethernet 10/100 network printers. Will attaching them to my switch slow the whole network down?

Comment: Of course not. Why would it? Switch negotiate the speed with the device connected and if errors occur you can change the speed manually on the switch.

Comment: why would it? I read that "All devices on a network will auto-negotiate to a common sped to a void incompatibility bottleneck" and "IMHO unless you ar planning to pjase out all of the 10/100 mgabit nics on you network don't bother going to gigabit" http://forums.smallnetbuilder.com/showthread.php?t=312
and also 
". One reader said that merely plugging a NIC running at 100 Mbps into a gigabit switch was enough to force all gigabit links to 100 Mbps speed" http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/content/view/30212/54/


http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/content/view/30212/54/

Answer (score 8):

You should not have an issue. Point to point should switch to what the device supports. If you were on a token ring it would matter. Through a modern router or switch there should be no issue. Make sure your switch does not have some sort of force mode enabled too.

Comment: is "force mode" like this "flow control" issue? http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/content/view/30212/54/

Comment: interesting http://superuser.com/questions/346532/what-can-cause-auto-negotiation-to-fail-on-network?rq=1