# Two gigabit switches show 100BT and 1000BT one opposite ends of the cable

Tags: ethernet, switch, gigabit-ethernet

Two gigabit switches of identical brand and model ([D-Link GO-SW-8G 8-Port](http://www.dlink.com/uk/en/products/go-sw-8g-8-port-gigabit-dlinkgo-switch)) are connected. This model shows a green LED light in gigabit mode, orange in 100 mode.

The two switches connected with the cable show green on one end, orange on the other end of the cable. Both switches are connected to other 1000BT and 100BT devices, so both do  work in both modes. This happens with a homemade cable as well as a pre-made [Goobay CAT 5-2000 U/UTP GELB 20m PL CAT 5e network cable](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B003KRA2SU/).

What does it mean, that they show different colors on the two ends of the cable?

Comment: These homemade cables?

Comment: Either the cable is weird or the LED is.

Comment: with a homemade cable, but also with this cable: https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B003KRA2SU/

Comment: Then it can only be the LED - have you tried another port or connected a 100 Mbit device to see if it shows a gigabit link? I've seen LEDs soldered in reverse...

Comment: I have tried with different ports of the switch and repeated the result. I also swiched the switches with the same reproducable result.

Comment: @dnz what's the make model of the switches?  It sounds like a duplex mis-match. / Something is failing in the IEEE auto-negotiation process

Comment: @Tim_Stewart dlinkgo go-sw-8g

Comment: Are you sure both switches are the same hardware revision? Does traffic go through? How fast is it? // I suggest using shielded cables at that length.

Comment: @Daniel b You suggest using shielded cables at 65.5 feet? With equipment that doesn't ground the shielding? And without grounded shielding the benefits are negated? 

Answer (score 0):

I believe this as being a couple possible reasons.

either some sort of

1. strange [MDIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium-dependent_interface) failure
   (not properly crossing the extra pairs?)
2. an IEEE [auto-negotiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonegotiation) failure.
   (if you have a rj-45 continuity tester use it)

either way it would be an indication of a [physical layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_layer) issue.

you mentioned that you have a home-made cable. if you have rj-45 crimps make a gigabit cross over cable, re-terminating the cable on each end. ( or re-punching if its a wall outlet.)

[image: gig-cross]

references,

[What can cause auto-negotiation to fail on network?](https://superuser.com/questions/346532/what-can-cause-auto-negotiation-to-fail-on-network)

image from - https://sites.google.com/site/mullais/network/what-is-the-defference-between-cross-cable-and-straight-cable

Comment: Actually I have a tester. I was only able to crimp connectors successfully by using the tester. The cables kept having to connection. I will do some more testing with readymade cables. But two questions: I thought one of the advantages of modern ethernet equipment was, that you no longer need to worry about crossover? and second (the switches were delivered from the same batch) how do you test the hardware revision (apart from looking at the sticker on the switch)?

Comment: You will find that in Enterprise environment's not many engineers trust auto-negotiation, or mdi-x. It's because it can fail, rarely. But it does happen from time to time.

Comment: Have you tried jperfing across the two switches to see what the actual throughput is?